# $\mathrm{lim}_{h\rightarrow 0} \int_0^h |f(x+h)-f(x)| dx=0$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have the following exercises: given $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, for almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have  $\mathrm{lim}_{h\rightarrow 0} \int_0^h |f(x+t)-f(x)| dt=0$.

My idea was to show first that this holds for an indicator function, then generalizing approximating an integrable function with a sequence of simple functions, but it does not work. Any ideas on how to prove it?

Comment: Try for uniformly continuous functions.  Then try approximating a function in $L^1$ by uniformly cont. functions.

Comment: The added condition "for almost all $x $" makes no sense. The expression you write down is not dependent on $x $.

Comment: Why is this on hold? Whats unclear here? Perfectly fine question in my option.

Comment: Sorry guys,I made a mistake while writing down the question. Now it should be fine.