# Is $\lim_{h \to 0} \int_0^h |f(x+h)-f(x)| dx = 0$?

Tags: lebesgue-measure

This question was mistakenly asked in [$\mathrm{lim}_{h\rightarrow 0} \int_0^h |f(x+h)-f(x)| dx=0$ almost everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041411/mathrmlim-h-rightarrow-0-int-0h-fxh-fx-dx-0-almost-everywhere). But it turned out that  the person was only asking for $$\lim_{h \to 0} \int_0^h |f(x+t)-f(x)| dx = 0$$ which is easy to verify. But is the statement true if you repalce $t$ by $h$?

I had the following idea to proof it: If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ then there exists a sequence of continuous function $f_n \to f$. Now

$$ \int_0^h |f(x+h)-f(x)| dx  \leq \int_o^h  |f(x+h)-f(x) - f_n(x+h) + f_n(x)| dx \\ +  \int_0^h |f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)| dx $$

now for every $n$ we have

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \int_0^h |f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)| dx  = 0 $$

and for every $h$ we have

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_o^h  |f(x+h)-f(x) - f_n(x+h) + f_n(x)| dx  \to 0 $$

But I was not able to conclude

$$ \lim_{h \to 0}\int_0^h |f(x+h)-f(x)| dx = 0$$

Am I missing anything, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is integrable (at least on a neighborhood of $0$), then we have 
$$ \int_0^h | f(x+h) - f(x) | dx \le \int_0^h |f(x+h)| dx + \int_0^h |f(x)| dx = \int_h^{2h} |f(y)| dy + \int_0^h |f(x)| dx \to 0 $$
for $h\to 0$.

Comment: o m gosh. I was trying so hard and it was so simple :D. Thx.